# what is the difference between fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and fcm.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/messages:send

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am confused which of the urls to use when sending messages to a particular client, the FCM docs do not do justice in explaining the difference between http v1 and Legacy Http server protocol

Comment: You seem to have the gist of it: the `v1` API is the newest (a.k.a "versioned") API, while `fcm.googleapis.com` is the legacy API. When possible use the versioned API. Is there any specific feature you want to know about?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am confused,  said "while fcm.googleapis.com is the legacy api " do you mean  fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: Yes. I got lazy and didn't type the full URL of the endpoint, but merely the domain name. But I still don't know what specific problem you're asking about. If you want to report a bug in the documentation vs video, you can do so on https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/.